# Objective-C fetch POST content with custom headers synchronously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, post, header, request

I need to establish a connection to myPage.php, send it certain POST parameters and use a custom header. All this I need to be done synchronously and the content returned as an NSString, and only returned once I have gotten the content, so I don't have to deal with asynchronous requests and set up delegates and stuff.

All that I need in Objective-C.

Do you know a simple way? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for your answers! But, just out of curiosity, is there a solution that doesn't require additional frameworks and libraries?

Comment: ASIHttpRequest is not a full-feaured framework, but a light wrapper around the CFNetwork stuff. It is a real time saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you cannot use ASIHttpRequest, just use a NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670029/nsmutableurlrequest-proper-posting).

Comment: Thanks! How do I get the content from an NSURlConnection, once established? In a synchronous way, without having to use delegates, but so I can just return it as an NSString?

Comment: Use + sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: of NSURLConnection, it returns bytes it downloads in an object of NSData type. You need to specify encodings to get NSString.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use), makes things quite easy